# Stale Redux state in React hook cleanup function (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've adapted a [with-redux-thunk](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-thunk) example from next.js. In this example, we are **removing** the redux state on the client, every time we hit the SSR page.

I have 3 pages, - 2 of them are Server-side rendered, and 1 is Client-side rendered.

My "Goal" is to reset the "redux state" whenever I go from Server-side pages to the Client-side page.

To accomplish the goal, - in every SSR page, I've added "react hook cleanup functions" in which I dispatch reset actions

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("leave ssr page 1");
      dispatch({ type: "RESET" });
    };
  }, [dispatch]);
```

But I noticed an "issue" - when I switch from the SSR page 1 to SSR page 2, the cleanup function dispatches a reset action to the "Stale" state without any effects.
It can be seen in the browser console via redux-logger.

**Question**: Is it a critical "issue", or I can just ignore it?

CodeSandbox: [issue sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sandbox-for-stackoverflow-redux-question-tqkpt?file=/pages/index.js)

[image: console log of issue]